# elementary OS LiveUSB boots and runs but fails to install

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, elementary-os

A LiveUSB with elementary os works fine, but it fails to install to my PC, which has no OS now. An error message appears "faulty drive" or "usb is disconnected."

That PC has two(2) ext4 drives and two(2) NTFS drives, and will connect to the Internet from the LiveUSB. How may I troubleshoot the installation failure?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details. What exactly means "but cannot install it"? Do you get an error message? Don't  you know how to do it? As you mention "ext4 drives": Do you have a different OS already installed? If yes: Which one? Do you want to keep it or delete it? If no: Do you want to use the existing ext4 partitions/file systems? Or can you delete everything and create new partitions?

Comment: Did you try to install elementary OS? What kind of error did it give you?

Comment: There is no os in the drive but has 2 ntfs n 1 ext4 partition, while instaling from usb it says faulty drive or usb is disconnected or something (i forgot )everytime i try to install and says it would help if you wip lens of cd drive but when live all drive works fine

Comment: @NiranjanRai Don't answer in comments. **[edit] your question to add information** Please answer all questions. Try to use a different CD/DVD or a USB flash drive.

Comment: @Niranjan Rai, please do `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Question formatting tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.